# What is an installation and development workflow in Strapi-3-beta for git and docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, strapi

I looked through the blog/site/tuttorials and I still cannot find an answer.

I need to make *reproducible configuration which will allow to have similar dev environment for all developers* in the team. I will highly appreciate any help or suggestions for the following questions:

1. What folders it needs to add into git repository and what folders it needs to ignore (to add into .gitignore)?
2. I set docker-compose configuration and I want to start Strapi -3 beta inside of the docker container. I do not like how it's done https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker/ - due to it regenerates whole project again for every developer.
3. Any ideas how to integrate migrations for MongoDB  into the dev process?

Comment: It looks like [Strapi is just a Node package](https://strapi.io/documentation/1.x.x/#getting-started-in-a-minute) and doesn't obviously have extensive host dependencies; why do you want Docker here?

Comment: I need  to make a monorepo with DB, Strapi (as back) and frontend site